# Circular cylinder $S=\{ (x,y,z) : x^2+y^2=1 \}$ can be covered with a single surface patch.

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

I somewhere found that we can take $U$ an annulus instead of a disc
where 
$U=\{ (u,v): 0 < u^2+v^2 < π \}$. Can anyone please explain me that how a cylinder can be covered with a single surface patch from $U$?

Comment: As Ma --- Note that someone has "edited" my original answer unjustly, so changing it that it became erroneous. I put up another answer,

Comment: @Narasimham It's OK I was just surprised and had to re-do it. Of course if you want to put an answer it can be done without editing another answer already there, just as your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

Any point in the annulus $U$ is uniquely of the form $(t \cos \theta, t \sin \theta)$ for some real $t \in (0,\sqrt{\pi}), \theta \in [0,2\pi).$ Map this point to the point of the cylinder $(x,y,z)=(\cos \theta, \sin \theta, \cot t^2).$ This is clearly a subset of the cylinder as it satisfies $x^2+y^2=1.$ Also, because $\theta$ ranges in $[0,2\pi),$ for any fixed $z$ the entire slice of the cylinder at that $z$ level gets covered. Finally, because the cotangent of $t^2$ for $t \in (0,\sqrt{\pi})$ takes on *every* real value, every level $z$ indeed gets hit, showing the result of mapping the annulus as above covers the whole cylinder.

Comment: I took the liberty to add a backslash ;)

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes that kind of editing is welcome, as opposed to what some user did to my first version (now deleted). I was a bit miffed when I wrote the last sentence of paragraph one...

Comment: Understandably. In the long run, since such things don't really belong in an answer, that should be edited out. But leaving it there while you're still miffed is okay.

Comment: I'm just curious why a cotangent is used here. Couldn't it just be $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta,t)$ $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$, $t\in\mathbb{R}$? Or is there a specific need for bounded sets?

Comment: @jdods The cotangent is because in OP question a map from the annulus to the cylinder is required. The OP's annulus is not just the punctured plane, and also one wants to cover all $z \in \mathbb{R}.$ Since the radius of the annulus ranges in $(0,\sqrt{\pi}),$ the latter interval had to map somehow onto the reals. [The annulus is in 2-D rather than 3-D so using a triple in the map isn't exactly right,]

Comment: ok, I see, so the goal was to map the annulus to the cylinder. That was unclear from the question for me. Thanks!

Comment: @coffeemath why we need annulus in 2-D to cover the whole unit cylinder?

Comment: generally we need a open set in 2-D for homeomorphism.

Comment: @AsMa You're right that one generally only needs a "reasonably nice" 2-D open set with a hole in it to cover the cylinder. Your question was about the specific annulus you define as $U,$ and how to map that one. [I thought maybe the $\pi$ on the right should be a $\pi^2,$ which would make the annulus have radius $\pi$ and the map a bit simpler looking.]

Comment: @ coffeemath yes I mentioned a specific dics in the question but I don't know the reason behind using annulus instead of a disc.

Comment: @AsMa If by a disc you mean something of form $D: x^2+y^2<r^2,$ i.e. the interior of a circle (including the origin as the annulus does not), then there is no homeomorphism to the cylinder, since the latter has nontrivial fundamental group but $D$ has trivial fundamental group.

Answer (score 0):

Parametrization

EDIT1:

For Cylinder

$$ a=1 ; $$

$$ (a \cos u, a \sin u, v),(u,0, 2 \pi),(v,v1,v2) $$

where z coordinate is depth or height of cylinder between two limits.

For Annulus

$$ a=1 ; $$

$$ (a v  \cos u, a v  \sin u, 0 ),(u,0, 2 \pi),(v,v1,v2) $$

Comment: In OP question, cylinder radius is $1$ so $a$ not needed. Also the triple you have would be for points on the cylinder, and need a map from the annulus onto the cylinder,

Comment: Is that standard differential geometry notation? $(u,0,2\pi)$ for $0<u<2\pi$?